# getJSON array error

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have a file with an array like this:

```
<script>
var articles = [
[
"Vanilla JS Browser Default Java Script.",
"http://www.9lessons.info/2015/09/vanilla-js-browser-default-java-script.html"
],
[
"Facebook Style Background Image Upload and Position Adjustment.",
"http://www.9lessons.info/2015/02/facebook-style-background-image-upload.html"
],
[
"Create a RESTful services using Slim PHP Framework",
"http://www.9lessons.info/2014/12/create-restful-services-using-slim-php.html"
],

[
"Pagination with Jquery, PHP, Ajax and MySQL.",
"http://www.9lessons.info/2010/10/pagination-with-jquery-php-ajax-and.html"
],
[
"Ajax Select and Upload Multiple Images with Jquery",
"http://www.9lessons.info/2013/09/multiple-ajax-image-upload-jquery.html"
]
];
</script>
```

and in other file I have a function with the getJSON where it going to get the array :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                /*
                 $("#notificationButton").click(function(){
                 var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1); // Random number between 1 to 10 
                 var title =articles[x][0];
                 var desc ='Most popular article.';
                 var url =articles[x][1];
                 notifyBrowser(title,desc,url);
                 return false;
                 });
                 */ var title;
                    var desc;
                    var url;
                    $.getJSON("data.php", function (data) {
                    var articles = [];
                    articles = data;
                    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1); /* Random number between 1 to 10*/
                    title = articles[x][0];
                    desc = 'Most popular article.';
                    url = articles[x][1];   
                    });   
                    notifyBrowser(title, desc, url);

            });
```

My problem is that im not getting the var title, desc and url in notifyBrowser(title, desc, url); because notifyBrowser(title, desc, url); does work inside the getJSON. what can I do?

Comment: First code snipplet is not JSON.

Comment: @epascarello - sorry

Comment: call notifyBrowser inside the getJSON, callbackfunction @StanickRS

Comment: try calling the notifyBrowser within the done call

Comment: Do you understand that getJSON is synchronous so the call to notifyBrowser executes before the code is run inside the Ajax success method? What you basically are doing is you called the pizza place for a pizza and soon as you hang up, you try to eat the pizza. You need to wait for the pizza to show up, so you need to put the call inside of the callback.

Comment: @epascarello - the getjson call is getting the array in array.php file to use the data for a web push function

Comment: @epascarello - but if i put the notifyBrowser(title, desc, url); inside it does work

Comment: *"inside it does work"* It should work...

Comment: @epascarello - i know but the notifyBrowser(title, desc, url); goes to function notifyBrowser(title, desc, url)

Comment: and with it inside the function notifyBrowser(title, desc, url)  is not working

Comment: I do not know what is not working since I have no clue what data.php is returning exactly. If it is returning the first code block, that are you actually returning it with a script tag and the var declaration, or just the object?

Comment: it should return the array the var article

Comment: And you are positive it is returning the array?  `console.log(data)` shows the array?

Comment: yeah i think its not returning

Comment: So add an error handler to the Ajax call and see what it says.

Comment: @epascarello - it give me an error and i cant find a way to correct this im new at json

Comment: SO what is the error?